# Custom dropdown filter for blogs not working for multiple filters - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a wordpress website. In blogs page, I have created `select dropdown` filters, if i write code for single filter then it's working, If i write code for multiple filters then it's not working.
**Page:**
[image]
See filters in front-end. And now, **see the code:**

```
$filter_model = $_POST['filter_model'];
$args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'ad',
        'meta_key'     => 'model',
        'meta_value'   => $filter_model,
    );
```

It's for single filter, if i do this, then filter is working and posts are appearing in front-end.

```
$filter_model = $_POST['filter_model'];
$filter_year = $_POST['filter_year'];
$args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'ad',
        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key'     => 'model',
                                'value'   => $filter_model,
                                'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
                            ),
                            array(
                                'key'     => 'ad_year',
                                'value'   => $filter_year,
                                'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
                            ),
                        ),
    );
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

It;s for multiple filters, if i do this then filters are not working and posts are not appearing in front-end.
Can you please help me where i am wrong, and how can i filter multiple meta keys. I am stuck.

Comment: Why are you comparing with 'NOT LIKE'?

Comment: My mistake......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change `'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',` to `'compare' => '=',`. This should work.